# filter rows in a text file based on rows of another file in R or python

Tags: python, r, file, row

I have 2 text files. File1 has one column containing some names. file2 has 50 columns and the first column has names and the next ones are values. All of the names in file1 are in file2 (2 is much bigger). I am looking for those names of file1 with corresponding rows in file2 and import those rows in a new file.
file2:

```
"ENSG00000000003.10"    17.83196398 69.91920499
"ENSG00000000419.8" 27.0839105  57.01053354
"ENSG00000000457.9" 15.09256081 14.86654192
"ENSG00000000460.12"    3.824827056 11.81359135
"ENSG00000000938.8" 21.29498307 26.8460545
"ENSG00000000971.11"    324.9552392 581.2884261
"ENSG00000001036.9" 51.89359951 77.12018624
"ENSG00000001084.6" 39.79887612 105.2936106
```

file1:

```
"ENSG00000000003.10"
"ENSG00000000419.8"
"ENSG00000000457.9"
```

output:

```
"ENSG00000000003.10"    17.83196398 69.91920499
"ENSG00000000419.8" 27.0839105  57.01053354
"ENSG00000000457.9" 15.09256081 14.86654192
```

Comment: @moin Do you know how to install packages in R?

Comment: I know but to install this package I really have problem!

Comment: I am working on the server

Answer (score 2):

Using `inner_join()` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d3 <- inner_join(d1, d2, by="name")
```

You get:

```
> d3
                name   value1   value2
1 ENSG00000000003.10 17.83196 69.91920
2  ENSG00000000419.8 27.08391 57.01053
3  ENSG00000000457.9 15.09256 14.86654
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the files are in csv format with headers.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('first_file.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('second_file.csv')

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Name'])
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do this efficiently with R using the `data.table` package (you didn't provide column names so I assumed your first column in `file2` is called `V1`)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(file2), V1)[file1]
# 1: ENSG00000000003.10 17.83196 69.91920
# 2:  ENSG00000000419.8 27.08391 57.01053
# 3:  ENSG00000000457.9 15.09256 14.86654
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory-map the larger file and do regular expression searches using the names from the first file.  I'm assuming that your names are unique, but you could use re.findall instead of re.search if they are not.  This example works with Python 3.4, where a memory map behaves like a bytearray object.

```
import re
import mmap
output = []
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f2.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for line in open('file1.txt', 'r'):
        pattern = bytes(line.rstrip() + ".*", 'utf-8')
        nameMatch = re.search(pattern, mm)
        if nameMatch:
            output.append(str(nameMatch.group(), 'utf-8'))
    mm.close()
```